# where i can download instagram source

Tags: android, android-studio

Is instagram source public ?

I want to make changes on instagram ( android client ) for personal use .

I need latest source code of instagram .

Thanks to every one :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is instagram source public ?

No.

> I need latest source code of instagram

You would need to join the Instagram team at Facebook. Or, possibly, use [the Instagram API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) to write your own app.